# Composer update fails. May be google-api-php-client related

Tags: php, composer-php

The following composer.json fails on **composer update**, 
with the following message:

Problem 1
        - Installation request for foo/auth-bundle dev-develop -> satisfiable by foo/auth-bundle[dev-develop].
        - foo/auth-bundle dev-develop requires google/google-api-php-client 0.6.* -> no matching package found.

```
{
"name": "",
"license": "Proprietary",
"type": "project",
"description": "",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:foo/ApiBundle.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:foo/AuthBundle.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:foo/ObjectKeyValueMapper.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/foo/Livefyre-APIs.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:foo/ImagineExtra.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:foo/EntityRepositoryBundle.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "pear",
        "url": "http://pear.php.net"
    },
    {
        "type": "pear",at"
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "pear-pear.pollinimini.net/Protobuf",
            "version": "0.9.4",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test-backend-releases/Protobuf-PHP/Protobuf.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/test/Protobuf-PHP",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": ["/"]
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.x-dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.12.0",
    "jms/serializer": "*",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.0",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.0",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.*",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "dev-master",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "v3.5.0",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "1.1.5",
    "predis/predis": "0.8.*@dev",
    "foo/api-bundle": "dev-develop",
    "br/signed-request-bundle": "dev-master",
    "livefyre/api": "dev-master",
    "basho/riak": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "1.3.1",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.1",
    "amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php": "1.6.2",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "0.2.*@dev",
    "test/object-key-value-mapper": "dev-develop",
    "bcc/resque-bundle": "1.1.7",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "0.4.*",
    "foo/imagine-extra": "dev-master",
    "ekino/newrelic-bundle": "1.1.0",
    "foo/auth-bundle": "dev-develop",
    "foo/entity-repository-bundle": "dev-master",
    "namshi/jose": "1.1.0",
    "nelmio/solarium-bundle": "2.0.4",
    "pear-pear.php.net/Console_CommandLine": "1.2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "1.6.4.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "fab local_bootstrap",
        "fab local_cache_clear",
        "fab local_assets_dump",
        "fab local_assets_install"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "fab local_bootstrap",
        "fab local_cache_clear",
        "fab local_assets_dump",
        "fab local_assets_install"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Any guesses?

Comment: It needs google-api-php-client, obviously. Take a look at http://www.4byte.cn/question/400717/php-composer-how-do-i-combine-composer-json-files.html - it looks like you need credentials for require`"google/google-api-php-client": "0.6.2"`.

Comment: I have included that but still getting the same message.
I have also deleted the composer.lock file

Comment: Have you added repository as well?

Comment: Yes, but to be fair I am now receiving :

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///opt/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:974

Comment: That could be because you've killed `composer.lock`

Comment: And what could be the next step now? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, steps could be to start over. Try to reinstall php, and your dependencies, keeping everything out of box, with google api. Maybe it will help.

Comment: So, I found a copy of my composer.lock and now I am back to initial issue.